# Few question about React - creating Weather App

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning and making react + bootstrap weather app and have a few problems.

How can I access a component "components/profile/profileWeather.js" from "components/main/mainInput.js" so I can create profile windows on clicking button “Add to profile”?

Also, how can I props API resources to created component?

I want to make everything connect to API every 60 seconds so it refreshes weather for every city user added to profile, any tips how to do it?

Here is GitHub repo: https://github.com/Macieyy/Weather-app

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide the relevant part of your code in the actual question. Also, it's important to focus on one problem at a time when asking a question, otherwise it will be impossible to have a 'correct' answer

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. As asked, this question is quite broad, and encompasses multiple questions in different domains. You access a component by importing it. You handle API responses as shown in a multitude of tutorials, e.g., make the request, set some state (or instance vars, or Redux state, or...) and either pass those values as properties like any other (non-Redux) or access them directly as props in a Redux-connected component. You do something every 60 seconds by setting an interval, or talking to a web worker, or... See? Broad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can make everything connect to the API every 60 seconds, but here are a few other things:

You can access your profileWeather in your mainInput by importing it.

on mainInput:

```
import ProfileWeather from ../profiles/profileWeather;
```

Then you call it like this:

```
render() {
return(
<div>
<ProfileWeather props.you.want.to.pass>
</div>
)
}
```

this way you just have to receive the props with the name name in ProfileWeather. Then, for example, if you have a state with some weather information, you pass instead of the "props.you.want.to.pass" and your ProfileWeather will have access to that information